# AWS Typescript CDK: Lambda Version Internal Failure

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I have the following code:

```
const func = new NodejsFunction(this, <function name>, {
    memorySize: 2048,
    timeout: Duration.seconds(60),
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_14_X,
    handler: 'handler',
    role: <role>,
    entry: path.join(__dirname, <filePath>),
    currentVersionOptions: {
      description: `Version created on ${new Date(Date.now())}`,
    },
  });

const version = func.currentVersion;

const alias = new Alias(this, 'VersionAlias', {
  aliasName: 'current',
  version,
});
```

I do this with a handful of Lambda functions all in the same stack. The first deployment works, however the lambda functions are created with random version numbers (some have v4, some with v5, some with v7).

Subsequent deployments then fail with a vague `Internal Failure` error message. So I check the CloudTrail logs and find a series of `ResourceNotFoundException` errors. The "Version" resources are unable to be updated because they have the incorrect version number stemming from the first deploy. How can I force CloudFormation to start at #1 for versioning my lambda functions?

Comment: Run `aws lambda list-versions-by-function --function-name <function-name>` for one of the misbehaving Lambdas.  What are the `FunctionArn` values returned in the response array?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no Lambda API (neither CDK, Cfn, SDK, nor CLI) to set a custom version number. Nor can a new version be "force published": _"Lambda doesn't create a new version if the code in the unpublished version is the same as the previous published version"_ [(docs)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-versions.html)

Answer (score 3):

For anyone visiting this later, the problem was with the following code:

```
currentVersionOptions: {
  description: `Version created on ${new Date(Date.now())}`,
},
```

Apparently you can't have a dynamic description as it is an immutable field